# Neighbours algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

Hi a have a code like these:

```
    for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
       for (int col = 0; col < a[row].length; col++) {
        // Do something with a[row][col];
    }
}
```

But i want to make an operation in a grid (8-neighbours) for every a[row][col] , however when im at the corners i will have problems (i don't know how to check if im in a corner), i was thinking in code a lot of if - conditionals, but i dont know the effective way to do this..
If there is a perse method for do this types of traversal neighbours arrays i would very greatful if you could give me a link, I've spent all day looking for information and I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these arrays which represent the changes in the indexes when you look at the neighbors from a given position:

```c++
int dx[] = {-1,0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1};
int dy[] = {-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,0};
```

At position `(row, col)`, `dx[i]` represents a change in `row` and `dy[i]` represents a change in `col`. You can use each position in the array to look at the neighbors.

Make a helper function that checks if a position is safe:

```c++
boolean isValidPosition(int x, int y) {
  return 0 <= x && x < a.length && 0 <= y && y < a[x].length;
}
```

Then iterate over all 8 positions and you will have access to the neighbors via `a[row + dx[i]][col + dy[i]]`.

```c++
for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < a[row].length; col++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      if (isValidPosition(row + dx[i], col + dy[i])) {
        // Do something with a[row + dx[i]][col + dy[i]];
      }
    }
  }
}
```